# Tags too low while editing

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, edits

These screenshots were taken while editing posts:

> [image: MSE]
>   [image: ELU]
>   [image: SO]
>   [image: Skeptics]
>   [image: Graphic Design]

As you can see, tags are not centered vertically.

This only happens when I have [full edit privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) (or the ability to retag inline) and I am editing without being directed to another page.

When I don't have that privilege, (or when I am editing on [a new page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/307456/edit), including while initially composing a question), the bug isn't present:

> [image: RPG]

---

- I am using Chrome (Mac)
- Sonic was able to reproduce this in Edge
- ɪʙᴜɢ was able to reproduce this in Chrome 64 on Windows 10

---

See also: [Margins off on tag edits](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3397/79217)

Comment: Confirmed, happening in Edge.

Comment: Confirmed on Chrome 64 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed in chrome too. Perhaps there was a change to the structure of the html. At present it sits with a span wrapping several other spans.

It would seem that by default spans get the rule `vertical-align: baseline`, which as a result causes the tags (which are spans) to end up sitting at the bottom of that space.

There is an existing css rule for `.tag-editor .rendered-element` which contains `margin: -3px 3px 0;`. Adding `vertical-align: middle` to this rule will fix this bug without having to trudge through changing any larger global rules.

```
.tag-editor .rendered-element {
    margin: -3px 3px 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```